# javascript listbox onchange lightbox not show

Tags: php, javascript, html, lightbox

I have a javascript onchange listbox it show value, but i insert lightbox code is not show. I want to add value listbox to link because i want to edit page is lightbox.

Example -> `<a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="edit.php?id=<?**listbox value is onchange**?>">Edit</a>`

How to use return value listbox to variable?

**This code onchange listbox**

```
<label for="country">Country</label>
<select name="country" id="country">
   <option value="1">Thailand</option>
   <option value="2">England</option>
   <option value="3">Japan</option>
</select>
<div id="selected_value"></div>
<label for="country">Country:</label>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="country">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#country').on("change", function(){
    //Get the selected value
    var selected_value = $("#country option:selected").val();
    //Write the selected value to our div
    ('#selected_value').html(selected_value);
 });
</script>
```

**Lightbox Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/plugins/pop-up/include/js/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/plugins/pop-up/include/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-content/plugins/pop-up/include/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../wp-content/plugins/pop-up/include/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '80%',
    height      : '80%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    hideOnOverlayClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    type        : 'iframe',
    onClosed    :   function() {
           parent.location.reload(true);
            }                
        });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To update a link when a new option is selected you can do this:

```
$('a.various').attr('href','edit.php?id='+selected_value);
```

Updated version of your on change function:

```
$('#country').on("change", function(){
    // Get the selected value
    var selected_value = $("#country option:selected").val();
    // Update lightbox edit hyperlink
    $('a.various').attr('href','edit.php?id='+selected_value);
});
```

I don't think you need the #selected_value div.